# How to make alerts work in php

Tags: php, http-headers, alerts

In my member.php page I have the following alerts:

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) == 'no')
        {
            echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
                "alert('You can't remove any more services! Please contact admin if you would like your account disabled');".
                "</script>";

        }        
        if (isset($_GET['success']) == 'yes') {
            echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
                "alert('Your details have been updated!');".
                "</script>";

        }
```

In delete.php I use the following code: (relevant code only)

```
if($numJobs < 2)
                {
                    header('Location: member.php?success=no&username='.$username);
                    exit();
                }
```

In update.php I use this code:

```
if(success){
                 header('Location: member.php?success=yes&username='.$username);
                 exit ();
                }
```

No matter how I edit the alerts, the alert `'Your details have been updated!'` is all that is executed. In the URL I can see the `success = no` so I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: change your condition: `if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == 'no')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) == 'no')
```

will always be false, since isset($_GET['success']) is either true or false and compared to the string 'no' the whole expression will evaluate to false.

Change it to

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == 'no')
```

like akam correctly stated in the first comment to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your first block has a syntax error; you need to escape the single quote, since the string is single-quoted.

Note the syntax highlighting here:

```
alert('You can't remove any more services! Please contact admin if you would like your account disabled');
```

Escaped:

```
alert('You can\'t remove any more services! Please contact admin if you would like your account disabled');
```

*However*, `alert`s are:

- Annoying
- A bad way to convey important information

Just add the messages as `<div>`s within the page, and stylize those or pop them up with JavaScript afterwards. Accessible and less frustrating!

Also, comparing the result of `isset` against something is usually wrong, and you did it twice. It seems like that should read, all told:

```
if (!isset($_GET['success']) || $_GET['success'] === 'no') {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
         'alert("You can\'t remove any more services! Please contact admin if you would like your account disabled");',
         '</script>';
}
else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
         'alert("Your details have been updated!");',
         '</script>';
}
```

Note how I swapped the quotes there; otherwise, you'd have to escape things twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you change success to 1 and 0 instead of yes and no, then you can just have

```
if ($_GET['success'])
```